# Installation of MySQL Server and connector/c++ on CentOS

Tags: centos, mysql

I am using CentOS 5.4. I am trying to install MySQL Server and Connector/c++, but i am unable from rpm package. Errors while installing

```
yum -i -allfiles  MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.i686.rpm
```

and

```
yum -ivh -allfiles  MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.i686.rpm

error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.i686
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.i686
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.i686
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.i686
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.i686
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the rpm library error,It seemed that the MySQL package you are trying to install needs higher version of rpm but you are trying to install in the machine which has lower version of rpm since lower version of rpm  doesn't recognise the library.

You can check the rpm package you have installed by executing the below commands

rpm --version

To identify whether the library is available in the machine by executing the command

rpm --showrc.

To resolve the case,You can try to install another package of MySQL built on lower version of rpm or upgrade the rpm package to higher version in your machine.

For libc.so.6 failure,you can use the below command

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6

Comment: rpm version is 4.4.23 and i dont have root acces on centOS server. So now i moved to sqlite3 to interface with c++ which is already install on cent OS.